# Which would be the Typescript Types for React Components that can return a string or directly their children

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Which would be the correct types for a React Component that might also return a `string` or directly their `children`, apart from a `JSX.Element`? for example:

```js
type PropsStringExample = Readonly<{
  returnString: boolean;
}>;

type PropsChildrenExample = Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
  returnChildren: boolean;
}>;

/*
  Fails with: Type '{} | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
*/
const ComponentReturnsChildren: React.FunctionComponent<PropsChildrenExample> = ({
  children,
  returnChildren
}: PropsChildrenExample) => {
  if (returnChildren) {
    return children;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>Just a wrapper around the children</div>
      {children}
    </>
  );
};

/*
  Fails with:  Type '"This component returns a string"' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
*/
const ComponentReturnsString: React.FunctionComponent<PropsStringExample> = ({
  returnString
}: PropsStringExample) => {
  if (returnString) {
    return "This component returns a string";
  }

  return <div>Or also some dumb div</div>;
};
```

Wrapping the returned string with a fragment on the last example is not possible either due to some eslint contraints i.e `<>"string"</>`

CodeSandbox with an example of the errors: https://codesandbox.io/s/type-component-return-children-or-string-b956g?file=/src/index.tsx

Answer (score 0):

A `React.FunctionComponent` must return a JSX element. A string doesn't match that description and would have to be wrapped in JSX in order to be valid. You could change the type from `React.FunctionComponent` to `JSX.element | string` (or something similar), but then in your consuming component you'd have to wrap that in a `JSX.element` conditionally or use a `JSX element` that makes sense to contain either a bare string or a `JSX.Element`. I might suggest that you rethink your approach here, or use a `<span>` instead of a `<>` fragment.

Comment: This is not the whole truth as string is perfectly valid react's JSX element ... not covered in TS (JSX.element) definitions ... for years.

Comment: Hah, thanks for calling that out @xadm -- more details for those interested https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/20544